# static html site on github -> jenkins workspace -> nexus repo

Tags: git, maven, github, jenkins

I'm trying to get Jenkins to (1) clone the git repo, (2) compress the entire directory structure and files into a zip/rar, and (3) send this off to Nexus.

What maven archetype or other method can help me do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use something like that o build your WAR (that is a comparable to ZIP / JAR)

```
 <build>
        <finalName>ROOT</finalName>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>WebContent</directory>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>build/</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </resource>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>build/classes</directory>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

If this not work, you can shell a script to fullfil your need :

> jar -cf $directory *

Comment: [INFO] Deployment done in 0.99 sec
Finished: SUCCESS

I had an epiphany about using the resource block! Thanks!